# why is ion-scroll don't showing in ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to do a part of my app scrollable. But just this part. Then I use  like this:

```
<ion-content has-footer>
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true">
        test test
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

But the test test test is not visible.

Do you know what Im doing wrong?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please provide it a height, then  it will be visible.

```
<ion-content has-footer>
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="height:100vh">
        test test
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```